# automatically starting GUI program on startx

Tags: python, pyqt, debian, x11, beagleboneblack

I have GUI code written in PyQt in `main.py` that I want to start up automatically after startx starts.

I've already configured my beaglebone (Debian) to run startx on power up.

I  initially included the following in /etc/x11/xinitrc:
    `@/usr/bin/python3 /root/PyQt/main.py`

This worked perfectly until I deleted some files from /root to create space on my beaglebone. I'm not sure what exactly  I deleted (mostly log files) but I might have also deleted the `.XAuthority`, `.bash_profile`, `.config` folder, `.dbus` folder.

Ever since then, it hasn't been autostarting my `main.py` on boot. Even now, after new `.XAuthority`, .`bash_profile`, etc have  been created, it still isn't auto-starting my program.

Is there a way to fix this? Or  another way to autostart `main.py`?

Note: I'm running Debian on my beaglebone and lxqt.

Comment: Superuser.Stackexchange might help you more in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local` then add the executing command at the end of the file right before `exit 0`. something like

```
python /path/to/file/main.py &
exit 0
```

remember to add `&` at the end of the command so the the command would run as deamon and won't stop the os from booting if it has an infinite loop in it.

Comment: unfortunately, this had no impact